# Unable to download financial data with getFin() in R - HTTP status is '403 Forbidden'

Tags: r, http-status-code-403, quantmod, financial

I am trying to download financial data of companies. I have used `getFin()` quite a lot without encountering any problem.

Right now, I am unable to download any data and when I use e.g. this code (and basically any other valid symbol instead of "AAPL"):

`getFin("AAPL")`

I get the following error message:

```
Error in download.file(paste(google.fin, Symbol, sep = ""), quiet = TRUE,  : 
cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance?fstype=ii&q=AAPL'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(google.fin, Symbol, sep = ""), quiet = TRUE,  :
cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance?fstype=ii&q=AAPL': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

However, if I try to access the website `http://finance.google.com/finance?fstype=ii&q=AAPL` via a browser, I have no problem with accessing the website.

So why am I unable to download data with `getFin()` in RStudio all of the sudden?

Comment: you may be being rate-limited if you are programmatically abusing the service

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your cache or going incognito and accessing the URL?

Assuming you are on a linux server and using PHP you could try updating your PHP version it should be on the Google finance api documentation

Comment: I am on Windows machine and have not cleared cache yet.

Well, it is working again after a few minutes. Could this problem have encountered due to fact, that I used url.exists to check accessibility of several symbols (and eventually urls) and hence google prevented me from "misusing" the service?

Comment: It could potentially be that, google is known to be a bit quick to penalise people for misusing services a simple code error can stop your web apps from working,have a look in the documentation to try and diagnose it so you will know for next time, glad you got it fixed Pat!

Comment: I am thinking about using `Sys.sleep()`. I am just wondering how many seconds I should apply after what number of requests.

Comment: Try duplicating the website onto another domain and hosting account and experimenting on it, that would be the best way to find the boundaries google have set, it's a shot In the dark but that would be the best way to find out, good luck!!!!

Comment: Well, I am encountering this problem once again. The only difference is that instead of `HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'` I get `HTTP status was '503 Service Unavailable'`.

Comment: Yeah it definitely looks like a penalty, Try dropping google an email and duplicating the site and testing it on another domain name, if it works first time it's a Google penalty if it doesn't work it will be a code error